# Adding buttons in acending order and removing buttons in decending order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently developing a simple web page for a school assignment and I was wondering it is possible to create a button that will add a button, also a button beside it to remove the button?

Basically a button called “Add Button” where if you click on it, a button with the same size(can be named anything appropriate with no functions required). No matter how many times I click it, more buttons will be added e.g. button1, button2, button3 etc. Also, next to “Add Button” button is a button called “Remove Button” where it removes the buttons descendingly e.g. from button3, button2, then button1.

Somehow not all of the buttons are removed. How can I fix this?

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="add_button">add</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="delete_button">delete</button>
    <div class="result">

    </div>
```

JS:

```
var start = 0;
        $(document).on("click","#add_button",function(){
            start++;
  $(".result").append($('<button id="add_button">Add'+start+'</button>').addClass('button'+start));
});
        $(document).on("click","#delete_button",function(){
            start--;
  $(".result").find('#add_button').each(function(index, el) {
    $('.button'+start).remove();
  });;
});
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/p8y672oL

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a place where developers codes for you, this is off topic. you need to show your progress .

Comment: @Rab there is a jsfiddle at the end.

Comment: I'm blind @Dekel I didn't see that

Comment: well... you'r not blind :) he added it right after publishing the question

Comment: with an extra h before the https, condemning us to manual copy-pasting

Comment: It would be nice if he included the code on site, as asked for in https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm sorry my bad its almost 5 am here been up all night :{ will edit it

Comment: First off, you are repeating ids.  Don't do that.  Secondly, if you select them all, `last()` will return the last one that you can `remove()`.  You really don't need the counter.  $(selector).length + 1 gives you the number you want to put on your new buttons

Comment: I have edited your question. :) Happy coding.

Comment: Why the `Java` tag?

Comment: Haha you ask the question with my code that i answer with it :-D lol. hhhh

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add dynamic classes, just switch from `id` to `class` for `add_button` and use `.eq(start)` to select the button.add_button at `start` index:

```js
var start = 0;
$(document).on("click", ".add_button", function(){
  start++;
  $(".result").append($(this).clone().text('Add'+start));
});

$(document).on("click","#delete_button",function(){
  if ($('.add_button').length > 1) {
    $('.add_button').eq(start--).remove()
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn add_button">add</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="delete_button">delete</button>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: You're amazing! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a start variable.  The number of elements tells you what the next number is.  You also don't need the size check for the remove.  Performing an operation on a jQuery object with a zero sized result stack will simply be ignored.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#add_button", function() {
  var index = $('.add_button').length + 1;
  
  $(".result").append($('<button class="add_button">Add' + index + '</button>').addClass('button' + index));
});
$(document).on("click", "#delete_button", function() {
  $(".result").find('.add_button').last().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="add_button">add</button>
<button type="button" class="btn" id="delete_button">delete</button>
<div class="result">

</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. You are amazing! Thank you.